# Issue while upgrading Grails to 2.4.0 from 2.1.4 & JDK to 1.8 from 1.7

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spring-security-ldap

We have an application which was implemented by grails 2.1.4 & JDK 1.7 which we need to migrate to grails 2.4.0 and JDK 1.8.

While updating to grails 2.4.0, below are the changes done from our end.

1. Updated all plugins in BuildConfig.groovy and application.properties files.
2. Many classes are deprecated, so I have used grails.util.Holders class instead of below deprecated classes.

   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.PluginManagerHolder
3. For few classes, I have changed the import packages as per grails 2.4.0
4. Latest richUI plugin is not available, so I have updated Holders class instead of ConfigurationHolder in richUI plugin groovy classes.

Built the war successfully and deployed war in tomcat.

Issue is unable to redirect the link from urlmappings.groovy to home controller and appropriate gsp.

1. Tried to redirect to another gsp within project(index.gsp) but it couldn’t.
2. Created new gsp(hello.gsp) and redirect to hello.gsp from urlmappings.groovy but it did not work.

When trying to load the application URL  http://localhost:8080/abc, it will redirect to http://localhost:8080/abc/login/auth showing page cannot be displayed

While debugging, control goes from urlmappings.groovy to bootstrap.groovy and further it is not navigating anywhere.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Adding Urlmappings.groovy

static mappings = { 
 "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{ constraints {
 // apply constraints here
 } }
 
 // Home
 "/"(controller:"home",action:"index")
 
 // Reports service urls
 "/services/report"(controller: "BirtReport"){
 action=[GET:"list"]
 }
 
 "500"(view:'/error') 
 }

While running the application I am receiving the below error in the stacktrace.log

ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pentaho/di/core/logging/LogLevel
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1967)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LogLevel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more

Comment: What's in your urlmappings?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Here is the Urlmappings.groovy  <br/>
static mappings = {  <br/>
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{ constraints {<br/>
        // apply constraints here<br/>
      } }<br/>
 <br/>
    // Home<br/>
    "/"(controller:"home",action:"index")<br/>
    <br/>
   // Reports service urls<br/>
    "/services/report"(controller: "BirtReport"){<br/>
      action=[GET:"list"]<br/>
    }<br/>
    <br/>
   "500"(view:'/error')     <br/>
  }<br/>

Comment: Please add it to your question, rather than as a comment.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Added to the question

Comment: Are you using grails spring security? If so, have you granted anonymous access to the index action on the home controller?

Comment: Yes, we are using Grails spring security. But I do not understand what is anonymous access to the index action on the HomeController.

Comment: By default Grails Spring Security denies access to all controller actions. So to make an action accessible without being authenticated you need to explicitly grant anonymous access. You can do that by annotating the `HomeController.index` method with `@grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'])`

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I tried adding the anonymous access did not work out. I am adding the error stacktrace from the log file in the question. Does it tell anything?

Comment: What are you doing that produces that error?

Comment: During grails run-app I am receiving this error and it is not deploying.